# Haskell: Scope of a variable

Tags: variables, haskell, scope, char

I am creating a function that given a list of `Char`, gives the same list but only with the numbers:

```
algarismos :: [Char] -> [Char]

algarismos [] = []
algarismos (x:xs) | (isDigit x) =x:(algarismos xs)
                  |  otherwise =(algarismos xs)
```

I get the error message

```
error: Variable not in scope: isDigit :: Char -> Bool
```

Why does it say `isDigit` doesn't have variable in scope if the `x` is there?

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Please always include the actual error message. — The problem you're experiencing is probably that [`isDigit` _itself_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit) is not in scope. Have you actually imported `Data.Char`?

Comment: error:
Variable not in scope: isDigit :: Char -> Bool
   |
6 | algarismos (x:xs) | (isDigit x) =x:(algarismos xs)

Comment: In my experience, compared to other languages, examples of Haskell code are more likely to assume that you will know which imports are necessary for the example to work (and to know which third-party library to install for the import to work).

Answer (score 5):

As long as you're giving us all your code, this is the actual error message:

```
error: Variable not in scope: isDigit :: Char -> Bool
```

This is saying that `isDigit` isn't defined, not anything else.

---

You need to import `Data.Char`, which contains `isDigit`. Put this at the top of your file:

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)
```

This imports the function `isDigit` from the base module `Data.Char`.

In the future, look for the imports you need to make using [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=isDigit).